# Swift game not updating highscore inside didMoveToView

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

i'm creating a game with swift and the score works fine. The only problem is the highscore. I created a function called checkScores() to check if the score is greater than the highscore. But the highscore remains at 0.

```
func checkScores() {
    if scoreInt > highScoreInt {

        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setInteger(scoreInt, forKey: "high")
        highScoreInt = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().integerForKey("high")
        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()
        highScoreLbl.text = "HIGHSCORE : \(highScoreInt)"

    }
```

I called it inside didMoveToView.
I created the highscore label and the integer inside game scene, and set the label text inside initHud()

```
func initHud() {
    scoreLbl = SKLabelNode(fontNamed: "Geneva")
    scoreLbl.position = CGPointMake(self.frame.size.width / 2, self.frame.size.height / 2)
    scoreLbl.text = "0"
    scoreLbl.fontSize = 100
    scoreLbl.alpha = 0.5
    addChild(scoreLbl)

    highScoreInt = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().integerForKey("high")
    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()
    highScoreLbl = SKLabelNode(fontNamed: "Geneva")
    highScoreLbl.fontSize = 30
    highScoreLbl.position = CGPointMake(150, self.frame.size.height - 80)
    highScoreLbl.text = "HIGHSCORE : \(highScoreInt)"
    addChild(highScoreLbl)
}
```

When i run the game the highscore remains at zero. I tried to put the checkScore() inside didBeginContact and works fine. But why? Because the physics are updated every frame?
Is it possible to check it inside didMoveToView? thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Place this code inside update()

```
    var highscore = 1

    let userDefaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()

    highscore = userDefaults.integerForKey("highscore")

    userDefaults.setValue(highscore, forKey: "highscore")

    if scoreCount > highscore {
       userDefaults.setValue(scoreCount, forKey: "highscore")

    }

    highScoreLabel.text = "highscore: \(highscore)"

    userDefaults.synchronize()
```